# hook_form_alter checking $user->uid == $node->uid

Tags: forms

I need to check if the node uid and the logged-in user's uid are identical when the user is in the node edit form, and then add a class to the form if that condition is true.* The relevant code in my custom module currently looks like this:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { 
    global $user;
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    switch($form_id) {            
        case "custom_type_node_form" && "$user->uid == $node->uid":
            $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'test-class'); 
    break;
    }
}
```

The class is getting added even if the user isn't the author.

*Use case is that all site members with role X can edit nodes of type Y, but if the member editing the node is the author, I'd like to add some CSS.

I'm using Drupal 6.31.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey You can simply do this :-

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) 
 { 
    global $user;
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    if($form_id=='custom_type_node_form')
     {
       if($user->uid == $node->uid)
        {
          $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'test-class');
        }
      }
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: As this stands it attempts to do a `node_load(arg(1))` regardless of the form or the path - so who knows what `arg(1)` might be returning! I'd suggest using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` (and you can read the node directly from the form array in `$form['#node']`).

Comment: I had to change the `if($user->uid == $node->uid)` to `if($user->uid === $node->uid)` for reasons I am choosing not to investigate at the moment, but otherwise this was great, thanks!

Comment: These conditions you need to add yourself. I just told you the way to do it.